# Can I instantiate an anonymous class in the constructor of outer class?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public class Outer {
     public Interface Anony {
         public void callback();
     }

     public Outer() {
        OtherClass.foo(new Anony() {
            @Override
            public void callback() {
                ....
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But my friend told me that there is some issue in it. I created an anonymous class instance in the constructor of Outer, so the anonymous class instance implicitly references the Outer class instance, i.e. Outer.this. But at this moment, Outer class instance has not been fully created yet. So the anonymous class instance references an object with incomplete states, hence the issue.

Is he right? Thanks.

Comment: Anony is an Interface, not class!

Comment: yes, but new Anony() {...} created an anonymous class instance. Right.

Comment: @zEro Yes, `Anony` is an interface, but that's the syntax for creating anonymous class instances that implement an interface. The same syntax is used when instantiating instances of anonymous classes that extend another class.

Comment: Right, right. I need my coffee! :D

Comment: If you accept an answer, my vote is for Thihara's. He gave you a better explanation long before I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You friend is right, but it depends on the usage of course.

The problem is not in creating the inner class inside the constructor. The problem will occur IF the inner class accesses the outer class.

This is because any object will not be able to give normal grantees inside a constructor. All of the variables needed for the objects operations may not have been initialized, etc.

However if the inner class is put at the end of the constructor I don't see this problem occurring, but keep in mind this is a dangerous gambit because someone may modify the code and then it's wtf time with the debugger...

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do it, but you shouldn't.

This is an example of the anti-pattern known variously as "letting `this` reference escape from the constructor" - passing a reference to the object being constructed to another class from within the constructor. The reason you shouldn't do this is that in a multi-threaded environment, the class to which the reference has been passed may see the new object in a *partially* constructed, and therefore *inconsistent* state. This can lead to weird and hard-to-find bugs. This [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html) by IBM is one of many describing it.

What's not obvious is *how* it's happening here: Anonymous classes are actually *inner* classes, so they hold a reference to the containing class (ie `this` being constructed). The recipient class `OtherClass` may see, and even act upon, `this` before construction has completed.

Answer (score 0):

I built a brainf..k example of all the different possibilities I could think of:

```
class OtherClass
{
  public static void foo (final Anony x)
  {
    x.callback ();
  }
}

public class Outer
{
  public interface Anony
  {
    void callback ();
  }

  public class Inner implements Anony
  {
    public void callback ()
    {
      System.out.println ("Inner.callback");
    }
  }

  public class InnerDerived implements Anony
  {
    public void callback ()
    {
      System.out.println ("InnerDerived.callback");
    }
  }

  public static class StaticInner implements Anony
  {
    public void callback ()
    {
      System.out.println ("StaticInner.callback");
    }
  }

  public Outer ()
  {
    OtherClass.foo (new Anony ()
    {
      public void callback ()
      {
        System.out.println ("Anony.callback");
      }
    });
    OtherClass.foo (new Inner ());
    OtherClass.foo (new Inner ()
    {
      @Override
      public void callback ()
      {
        System.out.println ("Anony.Inner.callback");
      }
    });
    OtherClass.foo (new InnerDerived ());
    OtherClass.foo (new InnerDerived ()
    {
      @Override
      public void callback ()
      {
        System.out.println ("Anony.InnerDerived.callback");
      }
    });
    OtherClass.foo (new StaticInner ());
    OtherClass.foo (new StaticInner ()
    {
      @Override
      public void callback ()
      {
        System.out.println ("Anony.StaticInner.callback");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The expected output should be:

```
Anony.callback
Inner.callback
Anony.Inner.callback
InnerDerived.callback
Anony.InnerDerived.callback
StaticInner.callback
Anony.StaticInner.callback
```